# MSSQL Agent Task Failing - Stored Procedure

Tags: sql-server

I have a stored procedure that is giving me some issues as an Agent Job

When running the task, I get the following error:

`Executed as user: SQLUserName. Access to the remote server is denied because the current security context is not trusted. [SQLSTATE 42000] (Error 15274).  The step failed.`

The Task has 1 step and that step is just "EXEC dbo.Procdure_Name" and the "Run as" is blank (i'm unable to specify anything here). I have put in "Advanced", "Run as user" as SQLUserName.

When I remove this, I get the error:

```
Executed as user: domain\servename$. Login failed for user 'domain\servername$'. [SQLSTATE 28000] (Error 18456).  The step failed.
```

This is running a command on a linked server. When I remove that command it works.

The linked server is set to logon to "be made using the login's current security context" and testing the link server works fine.

If I log into SMSS as SQLUserName and run the procedure manually it works fine.

Would appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: What is the owner of the job set to?

Comment: @George.Palacios - The owner is set to the "SQL" username

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have put in "Advanced", "Run as user" as SQLUserName

This is not the option to use in your case.

Using this option you can specify the `user`, not `login`, to run your `sp`. However, when you connect to `linked server`, it's not a `database user`, but `server login` that is used, it's "**login**'s current security context" that will be used.

So in your case all depends on the job's owner. If it's `sysadmin`, the job is executed under `Windows account` of your `SQL Server Agent`, and if it's not `sysadmin`, the job is executing using job's owner's `login`.

From your error it seems that your job's owner is sysadmin, as `domain\servename$` is used. This is because your Agent is running under `Local System` or `Network Service` that when going on the network use your pc's account, `domain\PCname$`.

To fix you problem you can either change `job owner` to some `login` that has access to `linked server` or change `SQL Server Agent's service account` to `domain account` that should be mapped on `linked server`.

Comment: Thanks. Please excuse my ignorance here.
I have tried to change the "Job Owner" to my "admin" account for testing (domain admin). with the same error "Login failed for user 'domain\server$'. [SQLSTATE 28000] (Error 18456)". I assume that a domain admin account should have the suitbale access?
As for changing the SQL server agent service account. What is the "best practice" around which account SQL Agent service should be running as?

Comment: Thanks. I changed my service to run as a dedicated domain service account which helped this to work. I also had to make a few changes to my linked servers as there were some small permissions issues but overall working now.